# How to close dumpcap.exe using WinAPI? Dumpcap.exe is work by cmd.exe

Tags: winapi, qprocess, createprocess

I'm capturing packets with `dumpcap.exe` in a `cmd.exe` window:

`dumpcap.exe -i 5 -w:\\Users\\xyz.abc\\Desktop\\allPacketTMC.pcapng`

This capturing method works in a QT GUI. When I click the "Start LOG" button, it starts capturing packets. Below code works in QT Creator for capturing:

```cpp
const char *command = "dumpcap.exe -i 5 -w:\\Users\\xyz.abc\\Desktop\\allPacketTMC.pcapng";
std::system(command);
```

I can close `dumpcap.exe` in the `cmd` window with <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>. But I want to close `dumpcap` with the Win32 API (or another method).

When I click a button, I am reading all processes with `EnumProcessModules()` and can show their process PIDs. But the PID of `dumpcap.exe` doesn't appear, so I cannot close `dumpcap` from my GUI.

I used `QProcess` to create the process in QT, but it doesn't work in an opened window.

I use the `std::system()` function and close `dumpcap.exe` from the `cmd` window with <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>, but I don't want to close `dumpcap` this way.

I searched for how to use the `CreateProcess()` function for creating `cmd.exe` from the Win32 API, but I didn't run `dumpcap.exe` with `CreateProcess()` because I didn't declare the `lpCommandLine` argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply pass `CreateProcess()` the same command line you are passing to `system()`. `CreateProcess()` gives you a process ID you can use with `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent()`, and a process handle you can use with `TerminateProcess()`.

```
char command[] = "dumpcap.exe -i 5 -w:\\Users\\xyz.abc\\Desktop\\allPacketTMC.pcapng";

STARTUPINFOA si = {};
si.cb = sizeof(si);

PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {};

if (CreateProcessA(NULL, command, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE | CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP | CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
{
    ...
    AttachConsole(pi.dwProcessID);
    GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(CTRL_C_EVENT, pi.dwProcessID);
    AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS);
    // or: 
    TerminateProcess(pi.hProcess, 0);
    ...
    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
}
```

The alternative is to not use `dumpcap.exe` at all.  Use a library like libpcap instead and do the capturing yourself directly in your own code.

Comment: i doubt that this code ( `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent` ) will be work

Comment: @RbMm Actually, it does work. I tested it. I created a console app that just sleeps infinitely so it can exit only with Ctrl-C, and then made a UI app that uses the code shown above to spawn that console app and it exited correctly with `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent()`.

Comment: strange - i test with *cmd.exe* as console app. and `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(CTRL_C_EVENT, pi.dwProcessID);` not have any effect

Comment: @RbMm I tested again having `CreateProcess()` use `cmd.exe /C ...` to run my console app (like `std::system()` does) and `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent()` still works, but only if the console app outputs something to the console window. Otherwise, I see a blank window and `^C` appears in the window when `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent()` is called but the window doesn't close. Weird. In any case, the OP doesn't need to run `cmd.exe` directly to run `dumpcap.exe`, though, so in that regard the code I showed should work when running `dumpcap.exe` directly.

Comment: in case start cmd with empty command line - it also not work . however, ok, if will be work with concrete app. possible direct create remote thread to `CtrlRoutine` in target process (will be hard in case different bitness). most simply - use `TerminateProcess` i think

Comment: @RbMm using `AttachConsole()` avoids the need for `CreateRemoteThread()`. `TerminateProcess()` of course will "work" but is brute force and may leave the capture file corrupted

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help, guys.

I don't start cmd.exe. Because dumpcap.exe can work directly for capturing packet. So that, I started dumpcap.exe with `CreateProcess()`.

When I click the Start Button `on_pushButton_StartLOG_clicked()` function runs:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_StartLOG_clicked()
{
    thread  = new QThread();
    worker  = new Worker();    
    worker->moveToThread(thread);
    connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), worker, SLOT(capturePacket()));
    connect(worker, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(quit()));
    connect(worker, SIGNAL(finished()), worker, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    thread->start();
}
```

And also `capturePacket()` functin in here:

```
void Worker::capturePacket(){
    TCHAR commandArgs[] = _T("dumpcap.exe -i 5 -w C:\\Users\\abc.xyz\\Desktop\\allPacket.pcapng");

    if(mCloseDumpcapFlag){
        mCloseDumpcapFlag = false;
        if(bCreateResult){
            TerminateProcess(pi.hProcess, 0);

            WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
            CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
            CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
            emit finished();
        }
    } else {
        si.cb = sizeof(si);

        bCreateResult = CreateProcess(NULL,
                                      commandArgs,
                                      NULL,
                                      NULL,
                                      FALSE,
                                      CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE | CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP | CREATE_NO_WINDOW,
                                      NULL,
                                      NULL,
                                      &si,
                                      &pi);
    }
}
```

If I click the Stop Button, `on_pushButton_StopLOG_clicked()` function runs:

```
 void MainWindow::on_pushButton_StopLOG_clicked()
 {
    worker->closeDumpcap(true);
 }
```

`closeDumpcap()` function in here:

```
void Worker::closeDumpcap(bool flag){
    mCloseDumpcapFlag = flag;
    capturePacket();
}
```

`mCloseDumpcapFlag = true` happen. Condition that is in the `capturePacket()` function work for `mCloseDumpcapFlag = true` condition for stopping the dumpcap.exe with `TerminateProcess()` function.

Conclusively, i can start dumpcap from GUI and stop it from GUI.